# Vue router is not loading the page in Laravel app

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I am trying to load the vue router pages. Not sure what is wrong. Here is what I have done.

In `router.js` file I have

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
Vue.use(Router)
import testPage from './test.vue';
 
const defaultRoutes = [
    {path: '/test', component: testPage}
 ]
 
 export default new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    defaultRoutes
  })
```

and in `app.js` file I have

```
require('./bootstrap');
window.Vue = require('vue');
Vue.component('mainapp', require('./mainapp.vue').default);
import router from './router'
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router
});
```

in `mainapp.vue` file I have

```
<template>
<div>
    <h1>this is the main app !</h1>
     <router-view></router-view>
</div>
</template>
```

In `test.vue` I have

```
<template>
<div>
    <h1>this is the test page</h1>
</div>
</template>
```

I can see the h1 text loaded when I hit `/test` url but the `testPage` component is not loaded.

Anyone can help? Thanks.

Comment: does any error appear on the console?

Comment: nope nothing. everything is clean including the terminal (running npm run watch)

Comment: are you using laravel?

Comment: yes, I have installed a fresh laravel

Comment: tries to change the name of `defaultRoutes`  to `routes`.

Comment: did that as well. not working.

Comment: Hmm, 
I tried this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-water-lo2o3?file=/src/router/router.js) with your variable name it didn't work, I changed it and it started to work.

Comment: ok nice it works. yes variable problems. you can add that as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the name of `defaultRoutes` to `routes`.